# How can I generate NSManagedObject classes in Swift instead of Objective C in Xcode 8?

Tags: xcode, core-data, swift3, xcode8

I'm building a Core Data application using Swift 3 and Xcode 8 beta and when I generate the NSManagedObject subclasses Xcode gives me Objective-C files instead of Swift.

While I am very aware that I can simply write my own NSManagedObject subclasses in Swift I'd like to know how to switch the language of the generated code from Objective-C to Swift.

### Question

How can I generate NSManagedObject classes in Swift instead of Objective C in Xcode 8?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Alright, apparently I didn't look hard enough, it's right here:

[image]

Comment: I wonder if it works for you. I am always getting error "Could not cast value of type 'NSManagedObject_<my NSManagedObject class>...

Comment: @zeeshan I did have some casting issues when I first got going with Xcode 8's Core Data. The new core data introduces some new syntax. You should ask a new question.

Comment: Seems like it is working for me now. But it is true that Swift 3 has made some major changes in regard to Core Data.