# How to generate NSManagedObject classes in Objective C instead of Swift?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, core-data, swift3

I have coreData swift class defined as

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

@objc(Users)
public class Users: NSManagedObject {

}
```

Name of file is

```
Users+CoreDataClass.swift
```

I need to call this as

```
NSFetchRequest* request = [Users fetchRequest];
```

I have tried importing `"Users+CoreDataClass-Swift.h"` However its not recognising any class with users name.

What am i missing.

Comment: Please describe how you have setup your Model and let us know, what your target OS is. General information about auto created `NSManagedObject` subclasses can be found [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39931137/xcode-is-looking-for-core-data-entity-names-with-dot-not-compiling/39933534#39933534).

Comment: My deployment target is 9.0. i am creating models from "Create NSManagedObject class" Its creating swift only. and i need to use these into my objective c code.

Comment: Is it feasible for you to have the Swift classes instead of generating Obj-C classes right away?

Comment: Not really, i would prefer it to make Obj c classes but not sure it just auto generate Swift classes.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38287948/1457385) should work than.

Comment: @shallowThought oh man, thanks so much :)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can generate Objective-C `NSManagedObject` subclasses right away. To do so, change your Models settings accordingly:

[image]