# (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured .... in an objective C app.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

After adding a (Core Data) Data Model to an Objective-C iOS app of mine.
I get the following error message:

> “Swift Language Version” (SWIFT_VERSION) is required to be configured
>   correctly for targets which use Swift. Use the [Edit > Convert > To
>   Current Swift Syntax…] menu to choose a Swift version or use the Build
>   Settings editor to configure the build setting directly.

This is all the more surprising that the app is not Swift but Objective-C.
If anyone has seen this before, how did you handle the problem?

Comment: Have you added any entities to your core data model?

Comment: Perhaps "Code Generation" is set to "Swift" for the entities? Compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38287910/how-can-i-generate-nsmanagedobject-classes-in-swift-instead-of-objective-c-in-xc.

Comment: check if you have added any swift file in your project

Comment: There was no Core Data before and it was working. Then I just added the data model and one entity and I got the problem I described in my post. There is no swift file that I can see or that I consciously created.
And using the find command in the terminal I do not find any swift file either.

Comment: Did you check the "Code Generation" setting for the new entity?

Comment: No I didn't do anything like that..... In fact I just went to check and it seems it defaults to Swift. Would that be the cause of the issue?

Comment: @ Martin R : You spotted the right point. That was it, I changed Swift to Objective-C and it works. Thanks!